# Best option to store big key-value mapping on disk for high read-only throughput?

Tags: database, mean-stack, disk, key-value-store

I have a dictionary (simple key - value mapping between small strings) of ~1GB in size (which may grow in time) that I want to use for spell correction and autocompletion purposes. I was planning on keeping it in RAM, but until I gain some traffic I want to stick to free hosting plans, so this is not really an option for the time being in my case.

The alternative is to store it on disk (SSD) and use some limited (e.g. up to 128MB) clever caching (e.g. with a combined LRU/LFU eviction policy) to keep access times bearable. However, I'm not sure which form of disk storage I should use to maximize throughput. The options I have considered so far are:

Use a database:

- MongoDB
- BerkleyDB ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB )

Use a custom solution:

- https://github.com/spotify/sparkey

Just use the filesystem:

- have a file for each entry in the dictionary, 
  whose name is the key and contents are the value

Before I start getting my hands dirty and evaluate the above by implementing and profiling, I wanted to know, if anyone has done something similar before, what was your approach and results. Please note that the dictionary is only created once and **not** modified afterwards. That is, after creation, there will only be read (lookup) operations, and one 'correction/suggestion query' typically needs 15-20 lookup operations.

Thanks in advance for any useful input!

PS: I'm developing using the MEAN stack.

Comment: What do your searches look like? Exact key values? Prefixes? Similarity?

Comment: Exact key values. I'm using the symspell algorithm https://github.com/wolfgarbe/symspell A thorough description can be found on their blog, but, in short, I get user input, generate deletes (e.g. 'play' -> ['lay', 'pay', 'ply', 'pla']) and look them up. The dictionary keys are also generated by deletes of terms.

Comment: You could try to use the filesystem to get log(n) lookup complexity. Create folders 'a' through 'z', and in each of them a...z recursively. Entries for "play" will be found at the path "/p/l/a/y". Should be pretty good performancewise and trivial to implement.

Comment: Thanks! That actually sounds pretty clever, I'll definitely give it a try. If you post it as an answer, you'll get an upvote at least ;)

Comment: Be sure to put the value in a file like "data" though. Else you will get a collision at /p/l/a/y when you have play and playground.

Comment: I would personally go for Sparkey. It seems that it is designed exactly for your use case. Deducing from [this article](https://labs.spotify.com/2013/09/03/sparkey/), those guys seem to have the right attitude. Don't underestimate the [NIH syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here). If you implement your own solution, you will have to do testing, bugfixing etc. There will be effort!

Comment: Indeed, sparkey looks like it fits my needs exactly. And since there are  node bindings for it, it won't be too much trouble to set it up.